# What is the domain of a reference function called in a perl module?

Tags: perl, variables, visibility, perl-module

I would like to pass function reference to a perl module as follows.
Here is the main program:

```
#main.pl
use module; 
my $ref = sub { 
     # what if a function is called or an array asked?
     # is domain main:: or module::?
     print "Log $date ", @_, "\n" 
} ; 
define_log_function($ref);
```

And here is the module:

```
# module.pm
package module;
my $log ; 
sub define_log_function {
    $log = shift; 
}

sub other_function {
     $log and &$log("Calling other_function"); 
     (...)
}
```

What is the domain of the log function called inside my module?  What happens if I try to call a function inside my module?  Is its domain "main::" or "module::"?

Thank for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every subroutine belongs to a certain package, even when it's an anonymous sub. The following code will print `Foo Foo`:

```
use feature 'say';

package Foo;

  my $coderef = sub {
    say __PACKAGE__;
    foo();
  };

  sub foo { say "Foo" }

package Bar;

  sub foo { say "Bar" }

  $coderef->();
```

It doesn't matter that the `$coderef` is executed inside the `Bar` package because it was compiled inside the `Foo` package. Not only subroutines, but also other global variables are looked up in the package where the code was compiled in.

Note that you can switch into another package whenever you want, for the rest of the lexical scope:

```
my $coderef = sub {
  say __PACKAGE__;
  package Bar;
  foo();
};
```

would give `Foo Bar`.

Answer (score 2):

`$ref` lexical variable (defined with `my`) and holds reference to closure. Lexicals doesn't belong to namespace, only global variables can be accessed like `$module::package_global`.